# How to perform this pseudo GROUP BY query with Mongo/Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a bunch of collections in my MongoDB database. To illustrate what I'm trying to figure out, here's an example document named "Restaurant":

```
{ name: "Foo"
  categories: [Pizza, Food]
  visits: 10
  location: "San Francisco"
}
```

I need to be able to query for the top ten visited restaurants that have location set to San Francisco grouped by the first category in categories. Assuming all the collections have the same document format, how would that be currently done?

Comment: what do you mean by "grouped by the first category in categories"? Do you mean top ten for pizza in san francisco?  or top ten group by categories[0] whatever that happens to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to query for all documents with location of "San Francisco" :

```
db.foo.find( {location: "San Francisco" } )
```

Second, to find the top visited restaurants, you want to sort your results by the number of visits a restaurant has gotten. You'll want this list in reverse numerical order by visits, so we use visits: -1:

```
db.foo.find( {location: "San Francisco"} ).sort( {visits: -1} )
```

To get just the top 10 restaurants, we'll limit this result to 10 results:

```
db.foo.find( {location: "San Francisco"} ).sort( {visits: -1} ).limit(10)
```

Finally, to get the results "grouped" by category, we can just sort the results first by visits, and then within that order, by categories:

```
db.foo.find( {location: "San Francisco"} ).sort( {visits: -1, categories: 1} ).limit(10)
```

Comment: this does not perform a group by, certainly not by category. in fact this will just show top 10 visited documents in San Francisco sorted by visits (and only within the same number of visits will it be sorted by category array).  There is no way to do this at the moment at least until https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589 is fixed, then it will be easy to do this in the aggregation framework.